# Python-Flask render_template para user in session

Tags: python, login, flask

Buenas tardes a todos!

He realizado satisfactoriamente un login a una página (llamémosla **pag1**). Ahora necesito que a una segunda pagina (**pag2**) pueda accederse también si es que el usuario se logueó previamente. Se que necesito un IF que especifique a qué pagina está haciendo "click" el usuario, es decir si está intentando acceder a **pag1** o a **pag2**.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
@app.route('/user')
def user():  
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("pag1.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Esto de a continuación se que está mal, necesito algún if que incluya a cuál de las 2 páginas está intentando acceder:

```
@app.route('/user')
def user():  
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        if ............ : #usuario intentando ingresar con un clic a pag1
             return render_template("pag1.html")
        else: #por descarte el usuario está intentando ingresar con un clic a pag2
             return render_template("pag2.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Editado para compartir método login:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ["GET","POST"])  
def login():
    error = None;  
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["email"]
        with open("users.txt", "r") as file:
            file_reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in file_reader:
                if row[0] == request.form['email']:
                    user_found = [row[0],row[1]]
                    if user_found[1] != request.form['pass']:
                        error = "wrong pass"
                        break
                    else:  
                        flash("logged in")
                        session["user"]= user
                        return redirect(url_for('user')) # debido a esta línea aunque haya hecho clic en botón de Pag2, me manda a Pag1
                else:
                    error = "user not found"
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("user"))     
    return render_template('login.html',error=error)
```

Comment: ¿Porqué no agregar el nombre de la página en la url? Si el usuario ingresa a web.com/user, solo devolverá a un témplate, a menos que dentro haya alguna operación y dependiendo de ese resultado lo mande a distintas páginas. ¿De qué depende en tu programa que lo mande a pag1 o pag2?

Comment: Hols Diego. Simplemente tengo un navbar con Login - Page1 - Page2. Es decir que entra con un clic nomas, pero lo manda a la pagina de login y luego que siga a la pagina donde hizo clic

Answer (score 1):

### Solución 1.

Según tu comentario la respuesta que encuentro es simple, crear una ruta para cada template o botón.

```
@app.route('/page1')
def page1():  
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("pag1.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))

@app.route('/page2')
def page2():  
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return render_template("pag2.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

### Solución 2.

O si a fuerza quieres que solo se cree una ruta, debes pasarle un argumento por la URL y leerlo en el backend.

```
@app.route('/page/')
@app.route('/page')
def page():
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        argumentos = request.args
        page = str(argumentos.get('page'))
        if page == '1':
            return render_template("pag1.html")
        elif page == '2':
            return render_template("pag2.html")
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Pero en cada botón de Pag1 y Pag2 deberás tener un href de la siguiente manera.

> Para Página 1

```
<a href="/page?page=1">Page 1</a>
```

> Para Página 2

```
<a href="/page?page=2">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: muchas gracias Diego! voy a implementar ambas opciones y te cuento. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Diego, la solución 1 es la que quiero implementar. Tengo 1 sólo inconveniente: si hago clic en Pag2, me manda a página de login, me logueo satisfactoriamente, pero me redirige a Pag1, y luego debo hacer un clic en el botón Pag2 para acceder a ésta. Se que el problema radica en la línea (ver posteo editado):

`return redirect(url_for('user'))`

y tuve que modificar las primeras 2 líneas de tu Solución1:
`@app.route('/user')`

`def user():`